# How to change default rule of Google Translate when to translate 'you' to '你' instead of '您''?

Tags: translation

'您' is honorifics description of 'you', But ususally we may just want to use '你'. I find google always translates 'you' to '您', How to change the default translate rule?

Comment: Google always translates 'you' as '你' for me. Even if you get '您' for 'you' in the main field, there is a list of other choices that include 你, 儂, 爾, 你們 below it

Comment: Google translate is not based on a very large set of rules, that's simply not how machine translation works (or at least not this type of machine translation).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the same issue as you described.

Did you try to translate it into Chinese (Simplified)?

[image: google translation]